# Using BizTalk Hybrid connection to on-premises SQL from an application outside of Azure

Tags: sql, azure, biztalk

I have successfully setup a BizTalk Hybrid connection to my on-premises SQL server and it works perfectly fine from a web application that is hosted in Azure.

What I am also wanting to do is use the Hybrid connection string to allow a Winforms application installed outside of our on-premises network to utilize this hybrid connection to access our SQL server.

Does anyone know if this is possible, if so how do you configure the SQL connection string in code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the BizTalk Hybrid connection is intended for this scenario, but if I'm not mistaking, the Azure Relay Hybrid Connection should fit your needs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-protocol